# How to trigger ng-change event in a angularjs custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angularjs-ng-change, jquery-multidatespicker

I am using multidatepicker.js for a requirement that allows the user to select multiple dates in a calendar. For any change made by user, I want to trigger a ng-change event. I use a custom directive and implemented for the input field. Because the change event is angularjs, I am not able to trigger it in the custom directive.

HTML: I am using the below template, because I have the input field in ng-grid.

```
$scope.cellSkipDeliveryDateTemplate = '<input type="text" multidatepicker ng-model="row.entity[col.field]"  ng-change="updateEntity(row)" style="width: 150px; height: 50px;  overflow-y: auto; "/>';
```

and the custom directive is:

```
app.directive("multidatepicker", function ()
{
    return {
        require: "?ngModel", 

        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel)
        {
            $(function()
            {
                angular.element(elm).multiDatesPicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
                elm.change(
                    function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue($(this).val());
                    }
                );
            })

        }
    }

});
```

Could someone please help on how should the custom directive be so that it triggers the event with the value of the input as the parameter?

Comment: If you want to trigger `ng-change` you need to break reference on your `ng-model` binding. You can do this by reassigning your ng-model to a new instance. Example ngModel.$setViewValue(newObject);. I'll try to post a full answer once I get my head around your sample code. I am using ES6 so it takes me a while to decode es5.